# Clio API Filter data based on nested resource

Tags: clio-api

Filtering data based on a top level resource is straightforward, but what is the proper syntax for the url when attempting to filter based on a nested resource? For example, if I want to return all tasks but only for open matters, how should I enter that into the URL endpoint since the Matter Status is a nested resource under Tasks?

I do not see the method for filtering based on nested resources covered in the Clio API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you can only filter by the options Clio's API provides. For example when querying a [Matter](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#tag/Matters/operation/Matter#index), you can filter by an `originating_attorney_id` but not a `user_id` as the API doesn't provide a way to do that. You'll just have to pull in all the data and filter it in your code logic.

You can reach out to the Clio API team and ask them to add a specific filter option and see if they'll do that for you. I've found that they are at least willing to have a dialog.